# Why does running sudo rails server tell me irb is not found in any of the sources? Running ubuntu linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Okay, so, I can run `rails server` just fine, but when I want to make it listen on port 80 at 0.0.0.0, I need to run it as sudo... so, when I run `sudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80` it gives me an error:

```
Could not find irb-1.6.3 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

But I did run bundle install, and it says:

```
...
Using reline 0.3.2
Using irb 1.6.3.      <------- see, it's there
Using debug 1.7.1
...
```

What is going on?

Also, if I try to run w/ https, `sudo rails server -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:443?key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_domain/privkey.pem&cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_domain/fullchain.pem'`, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did something potentially dangerous, I ran `sudo gem install bundler` and then `sudo bundle install` and sure enough it reloaded irb (in green) and rails server now functions properly, including with https! Unfortunately, I was warned by bundler not to run it as root - that my app would be screwed up for any nonroot user. We'll see if I run into any problems...